# how to disable SET search_path?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I need complete names at dump code, no psql directive... So, how to disable the `SET search_path = schema` mode and enable use of direct expression of schema names?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that with `pg_dump`. If you really need that, you'll have to edit the dump file.

Maybe there is a better way to do what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: No way!?  Really?   Ok... Thanks to the confirmation... Well, I am using Java Spring-boot *db.migration* files... `SET` not works in there, all goes to *public schema*.

Comment: I'd remove the `SET search_path` command from the dump and use `ALTER ROLE ... SET search_path=...` for the PostgreSQL user that you use to restore the dump. That way you can force it into the correct schema.